# I cannot use Point entry into Graphical Modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, network, qgis-modeler

I would like to use a Point entry to get the point coordinates  in the map to add in the network analysis as a start point.
I have added the Point entry into Graphical Modeler, I can click on the map but I doesn't get any coordenates. 
When I use the analysis network tool "Shortest path (point to layer)" I haven't any problem.
[image: That's my model]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to an open bug where the Point Input does not work properly unless the model is run from the Processing Toolbox: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31969